# Playwright Expect Assertion Poll to check JSON property and its partial value

Tags: typescript, request, response, polling, playwright

So I have a response body that looks like this:

```
{
 "executed-date": "30-OCT-2022-15:15:140"
}
```

Now the currently I am asserting like this:

```js
await expect
  .poll(
    async () => {
      const response = await page.request.get('https://api.example.com')
      return response.text()
    },
    {
      timeout: 60_000,
    }
  )
  .toContain('30-OCT-2022')
```

But the problem is that sometimes other json keys has the value `30-OCT-2022`, which is resulting in false positives. So I want to ask is there a way to assert the partial value text `30-OCT-2022` with the JSON key `executed-date`.

Comment: what's `expect` lib?

Comment: @Dimava https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions

Comment: Why are you using `return response.text()` when it's JSON? Parse it with `return response.json()`, then you can access the desired key.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
test("api get response",​​ async​​ ({​​ request​​ })​​ =>​​ {
   const​​ response​​ =  await​​ request.get('https://reqres.in/api/users/2')
   const​​ respBody​​ =​​ await​​ response.json()

   expect(respBody.data.id).toBe(2)
   expect(respBody.data.first_name).toBe('Janet')
   expect(respBody.data.last_name).toBe('Weaver')
   expect(respBody.data.email).toBeFalsy()
   //console.log(respBody)      
})
```

source: https://www.way2automation.com/parse-and-assert-api-response-json-data-using-playwright/

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work as I have to poll the response. In your answer you are not polling it.